# How to animate ng-view in Angular Dart?

Tags: animation, dart, angular-dart

Has anyone been able to animate the ng-view in Angular Dart?

I tried using ngAnimate module and create sliding pages like in AngularJS. But it seems that the ng-enter does not work with ng-view in Angular Dart.

So I wanted to ask all of you if you were able to animate ng-view content using Angular Dart and if so, please share your solution.

Thanks in advance